# Triggering an event when an Azure Storage Account Table is updated

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

Azure Storage Accounts can raise events upon uploading a blob or sending a message to its queue to hook up and perform certain tasks. I could not find any similar events in Azure Storage Account Table raising when a row is added, updated or removed. Even there is no Azure functions to support such a scenario. How can this goal be achieved without having to keep polling the table to realize a change in its rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to trigger the azure function directly through the update of table storage, it seems no possible. [The azure function itself does not support table storage trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings), and then even the event grid does not support this feature. The following figure shows its processing scope.

[image]

The correct method should be to pass the event to the queue and use the queue to trigger the function.

Comment: can we have it implemented as a feature request?

Comment: @Arash It can be bound as input when request.

Comment: could you please explain how to pass the event from Azure Storage Account Table to the Queue? An example? Article? etc.

Comment: @Arash What I mean is when you change the table storage, send a message to azure queue. Then this queue store will reflect the changes in table storage. The reason of using this method to trigger is azure function not support table trigger but support queue trigger. I am sorry to reply too late. This is how to use the queue storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue

Comment: @BowmanZhu What type of trigger is being activated when a row is added/deleted in the table storage (is it HTTP, Event Grid, Blob, etc.)?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I guess my question is this: I understand how to send a message to the Azure Queue, but how do I create a function that sends a message to the Azure Queue WHEN the table storage is changed (row inserted/deleted). How do I implement the logic of listening to the table storage?